# putting int type into specific file

Tags: c, ncurses

```
fp = fopen("rank.txt", "w");
if(fp == NULL){
   clear();
   refresh();
   mvprintw(y/2,x/2-5,"File Error");
   sleep(3);
   break;
     }
     else{
       ch1 = getw(fp);
         if(score > ch1){
         mvprintw(y/2-2,x/2-(strlen(title)/2),"%s", title);
         mvprintw(y/2,x/2-(strlen(rank)/2), "%s", rank);
         mvprintw(y/2+2, x/2, "%d", score);
         refresh();
         sleep(5);
         putw(score,fp);
         fclose(fp);
         break;
       }

       else{
         mvprintw(y/2-2,x/2-(strlen(title)/2),"%s", title);
         mvprintw(y/2,x/2-3,"SCORE:");
         mvprintw(y/2+2, x/2, "%d", score);
         refresh();
         fclose(fp);
         break;
        }
      }
    }
```

If i run this program i don't know why i couldn't insert the int type into the file i want. after i play the snake game it always inserting a strange character into the file but when i open the high score menu it can show perfectly for a few second and then back into -1. If there somebody who know why please tell me where i got wrong.

Comment: 1) Indent your code properly. 2) Stop calling `strlen(title)` multiple times and store it in a variable instead

Comment: You have a parenthesis balancing issue, `if () { ... } else { ... } else { ... }` is invalid.